# How can i get directions between two locations with gmap component using jsf + primefaces?

Tags: javascript, java, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm new at using gmaps with java-ee I've learnt how to display it and make markers on specific location but I'm stuck in getting directions between two locations.
is there any way to get directions using jsf+primefaces ?